# Integrating Angular 4 with an External Bootstrap HTML Template

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular, themes

I have been an Angular1 developer and recently considering using Angular4 for a new web application project.

With Angular1, I used to purchase an 'Bootstrap Admin Theme' which came with well done and consistent CSS and a lot of JS plugins put together which allowed me to focus on the application itself. I used to insert Angular1 code into it in the areas where there was data manipulation and I enjoyed doing that. So I had the best of both worlds.

Is there any way, this could be achieved in Angular2/Angular4, 1) without really missing out the JS plugins the Theme offers and 2) without having to copy the CSS everywhere ?

Comment: As far as I know Angular2/4 is more or less different than Angular1, which means you will have to rewrite most of the code to be compatible with recent Angular releases. I cannot tell if JS plugins will run on Angular4 (maybe they will if optimized properly).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible but you will have to do 'some' tweaking.

**Template**

- First of all import all your js plug-ins through npm

  *npm install (plug in) --save*
- Then you will have to edit your angular-cli.json to include js plug-ins (js & css)

  "styles": ["styles.css"],
  "scripts": [],

  Put the path to styles & scripts in to array
- Then you should add main template css file in to predefined styles.css
- Next you should break up your pages in to components (view components and 'tag' components).

**Now about custom app dev:** 
Add your custom 
 - js in to *.component.js 
 - css in to *.component.css 
 - html in to *.component.html

(* stands for component name)

et voila...

Comment: Thanks. Will try this out.